# If/then/else in SQL Query

Tags: sql, t-sql, if-statement, case

I would like to check a date value in my SQL query. If a date is equal to a predefined date then do not print anything, ELSE print the existing date value.

How can I write it correctly in order to take the desired date value ?

I have the following query:

```
(SELECT (CASE 
             WHEN (PaymentsMade.PaymentDate = '09/09/1987') THEN ' '
             ELSE PaymentsMade.PaymentDate
         END)
 ) as dateOfPayment
```

When I run this query it works correctly when the date is equal to '09/09/1987' , whereas when the date is not equal to '09/09/1987' it prints '01/01/1900'.

How can I retrieve the dates values that are not equal to the predefined date '09/09/1987'?

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What data-type is the field `PaymentDate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CASE clause needs to return a consistently-typed value, so it is implicitly converting a space to a date (which is evaluated as 1 Jan 1900).

You have two choices:

- select a null instead of a blank space.
- explicitly cast the date in the `else` condition to a string.

Here's an (implicit) example of the former:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN PaymentsMade.PaymentDate <> '09/09/1987' 
             THEN PaymentsMade.PaymentDate
         END)
       as dateOfPayment
```

Comment: Yeah man thank you very much Mark , you are absolutely right :)

Comment: @user1552812 - Interesting, because your Question states that you get problems with the `ELSE` and not the `THEN ' '`.  This answer explains why the `THEN ' '` would be problematic...

Answer (score 0):

Use NULL, not empty string

An empty string is cast to zero implicitly, which is '01/01/1900'

```
SELECT CAST('' AS datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `CASE` statement changes the value in that field, but doesn't change which *rows* are returned.

You *appear* to want to filter out *rows*, and if that is the case, use a `WHERE` clause...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  PaymentsMade
WHERE
  PaymentDate <> '09/09/1987'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`NULLIF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) to replace a specific date with a NULL:

```
SELECT NULLIF(PaymentsMade.PaymentDate, '09/09/1987')
FROM ...
```

Don't just use an empty string, because it would be converted to the type of `PaymentDate`, which is probably a `datetime`, and an equivalent `datetime` for `''` would be `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`.